# Can you Split Full names to First name and Last name with Openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, split, openpyxl, columnsorting

I have an excel file that I have been trying to split the column(Full name) into 2 separate column of First name and Last name using openpyxl.
For example: I have

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
wb=load_workboo(path)
ws=wb['Sheet1']
```

Full name: Harry Surf

I want to change to:
First Name: Harry
Last Name: Surf

Much thanks if you can do this in openpyxl as I wasn't able to find any answers to it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your code merely loads the workbook.

Comment: Have you thought this through? What if you have a name like `George William Smith`? What is the first name, what is the last name? Is there a delimiter or pattern to tell the two apart?

Comment: Have a look at the similar questions on here.

Comment: @ GordonAitchyJay @ JvdV I have tried using the split() method with no avail. I have been stuck on this for quite some time. There's no middle name. The only delimiter so far is a space.

Comment: Then have a look at some of the q&a on here - that use find(), mid(), left() and len().

Comment: @SolarMike I have but they deal with Pandas, CSV's, or MySQL. I want to see if its less messy using Openpyxl as I am unable to find any questions on here doable with openpyxl.

Comment: Also works with Excel... Hint: find the space find(" ",A1,1) then use left and right or mid.

Comment: @Solar Mike I am not allowed to use Excel, the only other way I think I can achieve it is through converting it to CSV file but before I try that I want to see if its doable with Openpyxl.

Comment: @Solar Mike Thank you so much!!! I will go try that and come back if I am able to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it. Load the spreadsheet, get the `Full name` column, iterate over the cells in that column, split the cell's value, and write the values to 2 new cells on the same row but in different columns.

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os

filename = r"names.xlsx"
filename_new = r"names (split).xlsx"

wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.active

# Find the column letter of the "Full name" column, assuming row 1 are headers
for cell in ws[1]:
    if cell.value == "Full name":
        fullname_column = cell.column_letter
        break

# Add the first and last name columns to the end
firstname_column = ws.max_column + 1
lastname_column = ws.max_column + 2

# Write the headers
ws.cell(row=1, column=firstname_column).value = "First Name"
ws.cell(row=1, column=lastname_column).value = "Last Name"

# Iterate over the fullname column, excluding the header row, read the cell's
# value, split it, and write the values to 2 new cells
for cell in ws[fullname_column][1:]:
    fullname = cell.value.split(maxsplit=1)
    try:
        ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=firstname_column).value = fullname[0]
        ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=lastname_column).value = fullname[1]
    except IndexError:
        pass

# Remove the "Full name" column
ws.delete_cols(cell.column)

# Save the spreadsheet to disk
wb.save(filename_new)

# Launch the new file
os.startfile(filename_new)
```

Input spreadsheet:

[image: Spreadsheet before]

Output spreadsheet:

[image: Spreadsheet after]

Comment: The problem with this for me is the split() part as it gives me the error: "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1). I am guessing it has to do something with single names on the list without last names. For example, they just left their name as John.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now instead of unpacking the result of `cell.value.split()` into 2 variables, I store the result as a tuple `fullname`, and index into it within a `try` block, and catch and ignore any `IndexError` exceptions that will be raised if there is no last name. `cell.value.split(maxsplit=1)` makes the assumption that first names are only ever one word long, and the last name is everything else.

Answer (score 0):

So, easy using left(), find(0 and mid():

[image]

Formula in B2:

```
LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)-1)
```

Formula in C2:

```
MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1,LEN(A2))
```

Much less typing, but what about the obvious issues with those who have two family names etc